# How to change the height of a annotation callout bubble for a mapview

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom MKPinAnnotation callout bubble similar to default callout bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537259/custom-mkpinannotation-callout-bubble-similar-to-default-callout-bubble)

I've added a custom View to a callout bubble.
The view is too large for the callout itself.

Is it possible to change the height for a callout bubble?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom MKPinAnnotation callout bubble similar to default callout bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537259/custom-mkpinannotation-callout-bubble-similar-to-default-callout-bubble/3636431#3636431)