# Add a button to MapKit callout at bottom center (not accessory)

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mapkit

I have an interesting challenge.  I need to create a callout for an `MKAnnotation` that has a slightly custom look on my map.  It has a right accessory view, but it also requires a button in the bottom center of the callout.

Is there a way to create a button and place it on the callout or is it possible to move the location of the left accessory so that it is in bottom center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MKAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207), as you've tagged in your question. Loads of resources and info if you search - this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537259/custom-mkpinannotation-callout-bubble-similar-to-default-callout-bubble/3636431#3636431) seems like a good start to making a custom callout. You'll be able to add the changes to the look as you outline in your question.

If you want to change any aspect of the look and behaviour of the map callout you will need to provide a custom implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've already read the post you mentioned.  It's pretty good for placing a custom pin views but doesn't offer much for custom callouts.  I have found good tutorials that show good ideas for adding images and resizing the bubble of callout but I have yet to find one that explains how to place buttons (not accessories) in the callout.

Comment: If you follow the links through you should get to this post, it shows how to add an accessory button: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-2/. You should be able to move this buttom where you like in your custom view, plus add other buttons as required.

Comment: I found a site that gave has a good tutorial.  I found it here:  http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1.  Even though he calls it a "callout" it is technically another annotation view.